# WordPress WooCommerce ASP.net API WebHookHandler: The WebHook request must contain an entity body formatted as HTML Form Data

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, wordpress, asp.net-webhooks

I am trying to create a WebHookHandler for Webhooks send from WordPress WooCommerce in ASP.NET C#.

I started with creating a ASP.NET C# Azure API App WebApplication Project and adding the relevant references (Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Common, Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers, Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.WordPress). Added the WebHookConfig, WordPressWebHookHandler and registered the WebHookConfig in the GlobalAsax.

I then published the application as an Azure App Service.

My WordPressWebHookHandler is still the default of the examples and looks like this:

```
public class WordPressWebHookHandler : WebHookHandler
{
    public override Task ExecuteAsync(string receiver, WebHookHandlerContext context)
    {
        // make sure we're only processing the intended type of hook
        if("WordPress".Equals(receiver, System.StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            // todo: replace this placeholder functionality with your own code
            string action = context.Actions.First();
            JObject incoming = context.GetDataOrDefault<JObject>();
        }

        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
}
```

When testing a User Creation WebHook in WooCommerce I can see the request in the log as below.

[image: Webhook request log]

But unfortunately it is never received while debugging and I see below error.

[image: Webook request log error]

I am thinking maybe I need a custom WebHook instead of the WordPress specific one as this is a WooCommerce Webhook. Or possibly it is handled wrong in the routing and ends up in another controller.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to make some additions to Svek's answer as I now got my Proof-of-concept completed and understand a bit more about the receivers.

His answer pointed me in the right direction, but needs a little addition.

**WordpressWebHookReceiver**
Can take in Wordpress Webhooks of type HttpPost. This does not work with Woocommerce as Woocommerce sends Json Webhook messages and will fail the HttpPost validation which is build into the WordpressWebHookReceiver class.

**CustomWebHookReceiver**
Can take in custom ASP.NET Webhooks. The custom ASP.NET webhooks have a specific partner for validation which includes but is not limited to the 'ms-signature'. Even adding the header will not suffice as the signature is also used in a different way from out of the box Woocommerce to encrypt the message. Basically coming to a point that you can't integrate Woocommerce with the CustomWebHookReceiver without changing the Webhook classes of Woocommerce.

**GenericWebHookReceiver**
This is the receiver you want, which accepts basically a generic set of Json data and will be able to use the "code" query parameter to verify the secret which you can add in the web.config of your asp.net api application. I used this receiver to finish the Proof-of-concept and got both the signature validation as well as the deciphering of the message working right of the bat.

My basic class which I will start to build into a real solution can be viewed below and changes the JObject into a dynamic object in the methods I call from the class. As you can see I have two methods currently added, one for the customer create and one for the order create to call the respective methods which do an insert into Dynamics 365 (former CRM).

```
public class GenericJsonWebHookHandler : WebHookHandler
{
    public GenericJsonWebHookHandler()
    {
        this.Receiver = "genericjson";
    }

    public override Task ExecuteAsync(string generator, WebHookHandlerContext context)
    {
        var result = false;

        try
        {
            // Get JSON from WebHook
            var data = context.GetDataOrDefault<JObject>();

            if(context.Id != "crcu" && context.Id != "cror")
                return Task.FromResult(true);

            if (context.Id == "crcu")
            {
                result = WoocommerceCRMIntegrations.Entities.Contact.CreateContactInCRM(data);
            }
            else if (context.Id == "cror")
            {
                result = WoocommerceCRMIntegrations.Entities.Order.CreateOrderInCRM(data);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result = false;
        }


        return Task.FromResult(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem I figured you deserve the credits for the extensive answer which pointed me to the right direction. THank you again

Comment: Hello. I'm using WooComm 4.0.1 and I have tried our approach but it does not work for me at all. "Error: Delivery URL returned response code: 415" If I go and trigger the hook anyway I see it went thru in the wordpress logs. But on the .net side says in log: w3wp.exe Information: 0 : Processing incoming WebHook request with receiver 'genericjson' and id 'crcpn'. w3wp.exe Information: 0 : The WebHook request must contain an entity body formatted as JSON. Not sure where I'm wrong. Help Please!

Answer (score 5):

### Your WebHookReceiver is wrong

There is a mismatch of expecting HTML Form Data, when in fact it should be expecting JSON.

> WordPressWebHookHandler is still the default

**This is what is causing your error.** If you look at the `WordPressWebHookReceiver`, the `ReceiveAsync()` method implementation, calls out to `ReadAsFormDataAsync()` method, which is **not** what you want, as your `Content-Type` is `json`. So, you want to be doing `ReadAsJsonAsync()`.

**Solution:** Don't use the `WordPressWebHookReceiver` and switch it to another one that will call `ReadAsJsonAsync()`.

---

### Looking at the code

> I am thinking maybe I need a custom WebHook instead of the WordPress specific one as this is a WooCommerce Webhook.

You had the right idea, so I dug up some of the code to explain exactly why this was happening.

The code block below is the `ReceiveAsync()` method that is overridden in  the [WordPressWebHookReceiver](https://github.com/aspnet/WebHooks/blob/4bfeb36657f4f52459d4006c390a8d45375a6731/src/Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.WordPress/WebHooks/WordPressWebHookReceiver.cs). You can see that it is calling the `ReadAsFormDataAsync()` which is not what you want...

```
public override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ReceiveAsync(
    string id, HttpRequestContext context, HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    ...
    if (request.Method == HttpMethod.Post)
    {
        // here is what you don't want to be called
        // you want ReadAsJsonAsync(), In short, USE A DIFFERENT RECEIVER.
        NameValueCollection data = await ReadAsFormDataAsync(request);
        ...
    }
    else
    {
       return CreateBadMethodResponse(request);
    }
}
```

A quick search through the repository for classes that call the `ReadAsJsonAsync()` method, shows that the following recievers implement it:

1. DynamicsCrmWebHookReceiver
2. ZendeskWebHookReceiver
3. AzureAlertWebHookReceiver
4. KuduWebHookReceiver
5. MyGetWebHookReceiver
6. VstsWebHookReceiver
7. BitbucketWebHookReceiver
8. [CustomWebHookReceiver](https://github.com/aspnet/WebHooks/blob/4bfeb36657f4f52459d4006c390a8d45375a6731/src/Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.Custom/WebHooks/CustomWebHookReceiver.cs)
9. DropboxWebHookReceiver
10. GitHubWebHookReceiver
11. PaypalWebHookReceiver
12. StripeWebHookReceiver
13. PusherWebHookReceiver

I assumed that the [CustomWebHookReceiver](https://github.com/aspnet/WebHooks/blob/4bfeb36657f4f52459d4006c390a8d45375a6731/src/Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.Custom/WebHooks/CustomWebHookReceiver.cs) would fit your requirements, so can grab the [NuGet here](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.Custom). Otherwise you can implement your own, or derive it from this class, etc.

---

### Configuring a WebHook Recevier

(Copied from the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/webhooks/receiving/receivers))

> [Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.Custom](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.Custom) provides support for
>   receiving WebHooks generated by ASP.NET WebHooks
>
> Out of the box you can find support for Dropbox, GitHub, MailChimp,
>   PayPal, Pusher, Salesforce, Slack, Stripe, Trello, and WordPress but
>   it is possible to support any number of other providers

### Initializing a WebHook Receiver

> WebHook Receivers are initialized by registering them, typically in
>   the `WebApiConfig` static class, for example:
>
> ```
> public static class WebApiConfig
> {
>     public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
>     {
>         ...
>
>         // Load receivers
>         config.InitializeReceiveGitHubWebHooks();
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: I dont understand one thing in there. I'm implementing this in my web api project for zendesk? do i have to create a controller with route api/webhooks/incoming. and how do i call WebHookHandler class?

Comment: @coder771 You might want to consider searching online a bit, as there are a lot of different ways you can implement WebHooks in your project. I would start with understanding how the request pipeline mechanics work in asp net core before making the conclusion you need a controller.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the data format that you send in your request. You must use format of HTML Form as your error message said.

Proper POST data format is described here: [How are parameters sent in an HTTP POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request)

Don't forget to set Content-Length header and correct Content-Type if your library doesn't do it. Usually the content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: Hello Alexander, Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately Woocommerce / Wordpress sends the content in Json out-of-the-box which is also my preferred standard. I see many posts about receiving Json with ASP.NET Webhooks in general, however it does not seem to work for me.